# Get most recent bucket data of out of 10 buckets in Apache Hive,

Tags: hive

In Apache Hive, I have 10 buckets. Out of 10 buckets I would like to get the recent bucket data. Is there any way to identify which bucket created recently?

Comment: Please provide your coded attempts.

Comment: When some Person don't know answer then trying  to put question mark (?) on your question.

Answer (score 1):

Hive table bucket is a file. You can get create time with file names using `hadoop fs -ls` command. And hive has `INPUT__FILE__NAME` virtual column. So, you can get file name in shell, then use it as parameter passed to the Hive script for filtering by it. But bear in mind that files are created in parallel, and which is later or earlier may be not connected with data nor with command start time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for well explaining.